# rosmake youbot_driver fail

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I installed the ROS fuerte in Raspberry Pi then i installed the 'youbot_driver' .
When i try to build using "rosmake youbot_driver"
it gives an error which is as follows**

```
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:178:13: error: ‘oro_atomic_dec’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp: In member function ‘void youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::Set(const DataType&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>, youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataType = std::basic_string<char>]’:
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/youbot/YouBotSlaveMailboxMsg.hpp:174:42:   instantiated from here
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:201:13: error: ‘struct youbot::DataObjectLockFree<std::basic_string<char> >::DataBuf’ has no member named ‘counter’
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:201:13: error: ‘oro_atomic_read’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp: In constructor ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataBuf::DataBuf() [with T = youbot::SlaveMessageOutput]’:
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:133:10:   instantiated from ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataObjectLockFree(const T&, unsigned int) [with T = youbot::SlaveMessageOutput]’
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/youbot/YouBotSlaveMsg.hpp:141:30:   instantiated from here
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:104:17: error: ‘oro_atomic_set’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp: In constructor ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataBuf::DataBuf() [with T = youbot::SlaveMessageInput]’:
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:133:10:   instantiated from ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataObjectLockFree(const T&, unsigned int) [with T = youbot::SlaveMessageInput]’
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/youbot/YouBotSlaveMsg.hpp:141:30:   instantiated from here
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:104:17: error: ‘oro_atomic_set’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp: In constructor ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataBuf::DataBuf() [with T = unsigned int]’:
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:133:10:   instantiated from ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataObjectLockFree(const T&, unsigned int) [with T = unsigned int]’
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/youbot/YouBotSlaveMsg.hpp:141:30:   instantiated from here
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:104:17: error: ‘oro_atomic_set’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp: In constructor ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataBuf::DataBuf() [with T = youbot::mailboxOutputBuffer]’:
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:133:10:   instantiated from ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataObjectLockFree(const T&, unsigned int) [with T = youbot::mailboxOutputBuffer]’
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/youbot/YouBotSlaveMailboxMsg.hpp:146:39:   instantiated from here
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:104:17: error: ‘oro_atomic_set’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp: In constructor ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataBuf::DataBuf() [with T = youbot::mailboxInputBuffer]’:
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:133:10:   instantiated from ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataObjectLockFree(const T&, unsigned int) [with T = youbot::mailboxInputBuffer]’
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/youbot/YouBotSlaveMailboxMsg.hpp:146:39:   instantiated from here
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:104:17: error: ‘oro_atomic_set’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp: In constructor ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataBuf::DataBuf() [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’:
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:133:10:   instantiated from ‘youbot::DataObjectLockFree<T>::DataObjectLockFree(const T&, unsigned int) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/youbot/YouBotSlaveMailboxMsg.hpp:146:39:   instantiated from here
  /home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/generic/dataobjectlockfree/DataObjectLockFree.hpp:104:17: error: ‘oro_atomic_set’ was not declared in this scope
  CMakeFiles/YouBotDriver.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/YouBotDriver.dir/youbot/EthercatMaster.cpp.o' failed
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/YouBotDriver.dir/youbot/EthercatMaster.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/build'
  CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/YouBotDriver.dir/all' failed
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/YouBotDriver.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/build'
  Makefile:113: recipe for target 'all' failed
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/youbot/youbot_driver/build'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/mk/cmake.mk:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package youbot_driver written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/pi/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141024-154740/youbot_driver/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< youbot_driver [FAIL] [ 79.18 seconds ]                                   
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package youbot_driver. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                              
[ rosmake ] Built 3 packages with 1 failures.
```

**I am using wheezy in raspberry Pi
Could anyone please let me know, how to solve it ?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195856/rosmake-youbot_driver-fail/) by [Max](https://answers.ros.org/users/6412/max/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for what reason do you want to install youbot_driver on your pi?

if you want to control your youbot via the pi, you just need the robot_description and some launchfiles like

- youbot_oodl_driver.launch (.../youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl/)
- youbot_joint_state_publisher.launch (.../youbot-ros-pkg/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl/)
- etc (depends what you want)

---

Originally posted by [lebowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20622/lebowski/) with karma: 146 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0